# Upgrading CRM 2013 to 2015

Tags: windows, upgrade, microsoft-dynamics-crm, crm

I am in the process of updating my company's CRM Dynamics version from 2011 to 2016.

The plan was to go from version to version without skipping, snapshotting in between each version and testing functionality in a test VM environment, then deploying the same process (minus any hiccups) in our live environment.

I have copied our CRM VHD and spun it up in our test environment, making sure it worked before I did any upgrading. Followed the steps and was able to get it to 2013 no problem.

Next step was to go to 2015 -- This is where I ran into a rather annoying problem I didn't foresee...2015 is NOT supported on any Server 2008 OS.

So the next obvious step is to either:

**A)** Load up a new VM with 2012 R2 and start over with a fresh install or

**B)** Upgrade our 2008 to 2012.

This is where I am looking for guidance on the path of least resistance before I go to my management team and present several options on how to approach this dilemma.

My current CRM server hardware is:
Server 2008 R2
6GB RAM
Intel Xeon X3440 2.53GHz

Comment: Check there: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh699673.aspx They seem to use a trial key in the 2015 to migrate the data.

Comment: I ended up canning the 2011 to 2016 upgrade and went for a data import (which I am still working on). The general consensus on upgrading from 2011 to 2016 is "don't do it".

Comment: Ahh, thanks for the feedback. Feel free to add it as an answer too when everything will be finish, as it's always a good reference to know what went good and what went bad.